# Issue with conversion from Visual C++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-2012

I have a Visual C++ 6.0 project which I need to update and I import it to Visual Studio 2012 with no problems, however, during compilation, I get the following four errors:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void
> (__thiscall CTrendDlg::* )(int)' to 'void (__thiscall CCmdTarget::*
> )(UINT)'  c:\users\nima\desktop\ffls_scode\trenddlg.cpp   89
>
> Error 6   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void
> (__thiscall CManualDlg::* )(int)' to 'void (__thiscall CCmdTarget::*
> )(UINT)'  c:\users\nima\desktop\ffls_scode\manualdlg.cpp  175
>
> Error 7   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void
> (__thiscall CManualDlg::* )(int)' to 'void (__thiscall CCmdTarget::*
> )(UINT)'  c:\users\nima\desktop\ffls_scode\manualdlg.cpp  177
>
> Error 8   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void
> (__thiscall CManualDlg::* )(int)' to 'void (__thiscall CCmdTarget::*
> )(UINT)'  c:\users\nima\desktop\ffls_scode\manualdlg.cpp  178

The first error is originating from the following line of code, and the rest are similar:

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_CHECK_PEN, IDC_CHECK_GRID, OnCheckButtons)
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_REF_L1, IDC_REF_L16, OnCarriagePos)
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_VALVE_L1, IDC_VALVE_L4, OnValve)
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_SAMPLE_L_A, IDC_SAMPLE_L_B, OnDetector)
```

Where (as an instance) `OnCheckButtons` function is defined in `TrendDlg.cpp` as follows:

```
void CTrendDlg::OnCheckButtons(int id) 
{
    UINT    state;
    RECT    rect = {m_rect.left-60, m_rect.top-10, m_rect.right+40,       m_rect.bottom+30};

state = ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(id))->GetState();
if ((state & 0x0003) == 1)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case    IDC_CHECK_PEN:
        m_pen = TRUE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_LINE:
        m_line = TRUE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_BUBBLES:
        m_bubble = TRUE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_GRID:
        m_grid = TRUE;
    }
}
else
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case    IDC_CHECK_PEN:
        m_pen = FALSE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_LINE:
        m_line = FALSE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_BUBBLES:
        m_bubble = FALSE;
        break;
    case    IDC_CHECK_GRID:
        m_grid = FALSE;
    }
}
InvalidateRect(&rect);
```

}

my message map range is also defined as:

```
  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTrendDlg, CDialog)
```

Why is the compiler trying to cast `CTrendDlg` and `CManualDlg` type to `CCmdTarget` type? is there a change in class structure from VC 6.00 to VS2012?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab3z9tb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the parameter of the handler function should be an unsigned int -- you have it as a signed int.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple issue, I thought the compiler would neglect the slight difference like that in function prototype!

Comment: They are two distinct types each with a different range of values, that's a more than a _slight_ difference, and certainly nothing a compiler should neglect. As marcinj mentions, the C++ compiler in VS6 is certainly not the epitome of standards compliance, so don't expect code to be correct just because it didn't complain.

Answer (score 5):

Your handler should be defined like this:

```
void CTrendDlg::OnCheckButtons(UINT id)
```

So basically change `int` to `UINT`

Answer (score 2):

See here how this macro [ON_COMMAND_RANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/9ab3z9tb.aspx) should be used:

1) You need a proper signature, return `void` and the parameter should be of type `UINT`

2) Qualify your method with class name:

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_CHECK_PEN, IDC_CHECK_GRID, &CTrendDlg::OnCheckButtons)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

VS 6.0 is quite old, modern VS versions are more standard conformant.